# Sketch component for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sketchjs

Is there any sketchJS components for React?

I'm trying to find a sketch/canvas area component where the user can draw something and submit the result into a base64 field as in png/jpeg mime type. [SketchJS](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/) does it but I was wondering whether there is any pure react component that does the trick?

I'm new with Javascript/React and I see that sketch uses JQuery, is there any other alternative, because I do not want to add JQuery inside my project?

Comment: I'm afraid that as it stands, the questions is slightly out of scope of SO. You may have more luck on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't see the benefit of using React here. React is especially useful for model-based DOM-manipulation. SketchJS uses a canvas which is perfect for this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment SaphuA, the thing is that the project is in React and as I google around and read stuff is not a good practice to add JQuery with React. The sketchJS is a JQuery plugin so that is why I'm searching for another recommendation/solution

Comment: @tbo that is incorrect. Adding jQuery to a React app is not a bad practice itself. A bad practice would be to use jQuery to access the DOM in areas where React has concerns (for instance, manipulating the DOM, attaching event handlers, etc.). For this use case, there's nothing you can do besides adding jQuery. Many other useful plugins/libraries make use of jQuery too, is just a matter of isolating those use cases in a component and you will be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the information damianmr, so in this case I will give it a go, since   as I said I'm new to the js world